# Make sure that min() only retrieves one value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL query that retrieves data from a table that lists athletes' 100- and 200-meter race times. The query only retrieves the best race time of each athlete based on the `athlete_id`, it also wants to know if the race-time is a 100 or 200 meter-time (`event_code`).

So a runner can have several race-times but the query only gets the best race-time from each runner at each event.

The problem is that if an athlete have done exactly the same best race time two or more times, the query retrieves all those race times. How can I make sure the query only retrives one value?

Here is the code:

```
select r.*
from result r
inner join (
    select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
    from result
    where event_code = 1
    group by athelete_id
) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

Comment: What other columns do you *need* in the result, instead of just saying `SELECT *`? There could be a very easy fix. Also when do you plan to upgrade from 2000? There's an even easier fix in more modern versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I need the get several columns, result_date, competition_id, athlete_name for example. So I guess it's best to stick with SELECT * ? Can't upgrade the database unfortunately

Comment: So can you pick something else to break the tie? E.g. if a user had a result of 10 seconds on Aug 1 and again on Aug 5, which date do you expect to see in the result?

Comment: I guess something like that should work, I want to show the time that was made first, so 1 Aug in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pain in SQL Server 2000.  This would be much easier using row_number, but that requires 2005.

However, the idea is simple, you just need one more layer of subqueries:

```
select r.*
from result r join
     (select r.athelete_id, MIN(result_id) as minresult_id
      from result r inner join
           (select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
            from result
            where event_code = 1
            group by athelete_id
           ) rm
           on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
      group by r.athelete_id
     ) aft
     on r.result_id = minresult_id
```

The innermost subquery is basically your subquery.  Then, this is aggregated by athelete_id, to get the minimum result_id, which is used for the final join.

Comment: Right idea, but I get two errors on this (FastestTime needs to be in the group by) and you need an alias on two instances of athelete_id).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question a bit, but you can manage it somehow like this for all competitor like this:

```
 select MIN(r.id), r.athelete_id, r.result_time, r....
    from result r
    inner join (
        select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
        from result
        where event_code = 1
        group by athelete_id
    ) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
    GROUP BY r.athelete_id, r.result_time, r.... 
--(as how many column you have, except r.ID)
```

Try this:

```
select top 1 r.*
from result r
inner join (
    select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
    from result
    where event_code = 1
    group by athelete_id
) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

OR

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

    select r.*
    from result r
    inner join (
        select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
        from result
        where event_code = 1
        group by athelete_id
    ) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

Comment: This only returns one row. I think the intention is to get only one row *per athlete*.

Comment: you are rigth, the second example then in this case is not good.

Comment: THe first one also returns only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Largely a similar approach to Gordon's, but breaks ties using the earliest event (which should be the identity column, if that's what `result_id` is, but that's not always guaranteed).

```
DECLARE @event_code INT;
SET @event_code = 1;

SELECT r.*
FROM dbo.result AS r 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT r2.athelete_id, x.mintime, mindate = MIN(r2.result_date)
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT athelete_id, mintime = MIN(result_time)
      FROM dbo.result
      WHERE event_code = @event_code
      GROUP BY athelete_id
    ) AS x
    INNER JOIN dbo.result AS r2
    ON x.athelete_id = r2.athelete_id
    AND x.mintime = r2.result_time
    WHERE r2.event_code = @event_code
    GROUP BY r2.athelete_id, x.mintime
) AS y
ON r.athelete_id = y.athelete_id
AND r.result_time = y.mintime
AND r.result_date = y.mindate
WHERE r.event_code = @event_code;
```

Much easier in SQL Server 2005, of course:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT athelete_id, --... other columns, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY athelete_id ORDER BY result_time, result_date)
  FROM dbo.result
  WHERE event_code = 1
)
SELECT athelete_id, --... other columns
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! Gordon's solution looked a bit easier and worked before I had the chance to try this. I will try to convince the ones I work for to upgrade the database :)